# Get widget position in expand layout

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm new to tkinter GUI, and I'm trying to get the postion of an entry widget.

I have the following code

```
import tkinter as tk 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1200x900')


frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True)


text = tk.Entry (frame,  text = "test")  
text.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

print(text.winfo_x(),text.winfo_y())
root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to get the postion of `text` entry widget. I used `winfo_x()` and `winfo_y()`, but I get position of `0,0`.

I'm wondering how can I get entry's position relative to the root frame in the above case ?

I've searched on this, but did not found any similar question. I also tried `winfo_rootx()` and `winfo_rooty()`, which are also return the same result.

Thank you!

Comment: It's rare to need this data when creating a tkinter gui. Can you elaborate on why you need the information?

Answer (score 1):

Until the widget has actually been drawn on the screen, tkinter won't know its true position.

Once it appears on the screen you can use `winfo_rootx` and `winfo_rooty` to get the coordinates relative to the upper-left corner of the window.

To force the window to be drawn, you can call `update` prior to calculating the location.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1200x900')


frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True)


text = tk.Entry (frame,  text = "test")
text.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.update()

print(text.winfo_rootx(),text.winfo_rooty())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I often call `.after()` in the past,now I find a good way.; )

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA: `after` is the better general-purpose solution. Generally speaking, you shouldn't call `update` unless you absolutely have to. However, it's safe to do so before `mainloop` has started.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this can help you. 
Give you  results with format of:
width×height+xpos+ypos

```
import tkinter as tk 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x700+145+100')
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.place(x=50, y=50)
text = tk.Entry (root,  text = "test")  
text.place(x=10, y=43)
root.update_idletasks()
tst=text.winfo_geometry()
lab= tk.Label(root, text=tst)
lab.place(x=30, y=100)
root.mainloop()
```

try to customize it as you need.